# How to get distance with $near?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I can get my elements, with the following code :

```
$lines = $loc->find(
            array("loc" =>
                array('$near' =>
                    array('$geometry' =>
                        array('type' => 'Point', 'coordinates' =>
                            array(floatval($longitude), floatval($latitude))
                        ),

                        '$maxDistance' => 10000 //meters
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

This is the results :

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 5490003c815289663d8bbd95
        )

    [name] => My adress
    [loc] => Array
        (
            [type] => Point
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5.050948
                    [1] => 45.040419
                )

        )

)
```

But now, I need to get the distance from my given point.

Is it possible ?

EDIT :

This is the code used to insert datas :

```
$loc = $client->localisation->localisation;    
$loc->ensureIndex( array("loc" => "2dsphere"));

$loc->insert(
        array(
            "idobject" => $myValue
            "name" => $myName
            "loc" => array("type" => "Point", "coordinates" => array($longitude, $latitude))
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`$near`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator does not return a distance along with the returned results. It only orders the documents in the response.

Under the PHP driver the easiest form is to use the [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregation pipeline stage instead. This allows you to project a field in the results, or even use it in other pipeline stages:

```
$loc->aggregate(
    array(
        array( 
            '$geoNear' => array(
                 'near' => array(
                     'type' => 'Point',
                     'coordinates' =>array(floatval($longitude), floatval($latitude))
                 ),
                 'maxDistance' => 1000,
                 'distanceField' => 'distance',
                 'spherical' => true                   
            )
        )
    )
);
```

There is is a database command form for [**geoNear**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) as well, but direct command results are often not as nice.

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error :

exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "can't get query runner" }

Comment: @bahamut100 Do you possibly have more than one geospatial index on the collection? Notice that these forms do not specify a field because they expect only 1 index to be present

Comment: @bahamut100 Works for me without fail or error. I just tested the code myself with your data. As I said. Look for other indexes. Drop the collection before you create data just to be sure.

Comment: > Thanks ! it works now ! I drop the collection, and reimport datas, and now it's good ! 

But do you know what is the unit returned for the distance ? miles or meters ?

Comment: @bahamut100 GeoJSON objects return in meters and legacy coordinates in radians. The documentation pages explain how to convert between the two.

Comment: oddly when i try your code it fails with `"$geometry is required for geo near query"`